# Codeigniter using routes & 301 redirects

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, redirect, frameworks

I am in the process of deploying a new site which needs 301 redirects setup for existing links indexed by Google.

Can anyone suggest how using the routes feature & regular expression I force any links to use the new 301 redirect.

E.g. a route

```
$route['hotel/pages/([a-z0-9_-]+)//\.htm$/'] = 'hotel/page/redirect/$1/$2';
```

So i'd like any pages that following the following structure:

> site.com/hotel/pages/somesection/page.html

to use another controller where i'll setup the 301 redirect (I can do this bit)

Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do (built a quick local test and it worked):

```
$route['hotel/pages/(:any)/(\w+.html$)']  = 'hotel/page/redirect/$1/$2';
```

`:any` (a CI's thing) is much like `/\w+/i`  so it matches anything in the 3rd segment, and remaps to the `$1`; then you have a slash and then any character, repeated more times, and ending in '.html', which remaps to `$2`

Answer (score 1):

On apache, if the mapping is simple enough to describe with a regular expression, you could just use `mod_rewrite` and skip the redirect controller.

For Example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^hotel/pages/(.*)/(.*\.html?)$ http://site.com/hotel/$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Would give you a 301 from

```
site.com/hotel/pages/somesection/page.html
```

to

```
site.com/hotel/somesection/page.html
```